# Quality inspection python opencv object detection

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, feature-detection

We have a conveyor line it stops 4 seconds at the test system. What we need to do is detecting sticked logos; is the logo correctly sticked(logo sticked or no logo), do we have a quality defects like blobs, scratches, orientation defetcs? So far i tried tesseract ocr(it was a silly idea),  brute force matching, template matching, contour detection with opencv and python.The  problem here is if we have slightly changed logos, we need to change our template. How can we implement methods that dont require template alterations and works at least %98 correctly?
and there are too many methods and filters how can i find an optimal filter and the filter parameters for my sitution.
I have an idea but i am not quite sure if it makes sense or doesnt: What if i try multiple methods i mean all the methods that can be used with concurrent programming?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Some sample input images shall be helpful.

Comment: I cant share any input images, due to confidentiality

Comment: Helping with image-processing questions most often requires to see the images of interest. No images, no help, I'm afraid. Can you set up mock up stickers or something like this?